# How to add an item with a predefined language using Sitecore?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

For a project I'm using Sitecore 6.5. It's a *multi-language* project. I want to *add* an *item* in *programcode* with a **predefined languange**, for example Dutch.

I searched the whole internet, but I can't find the right way. Does anyone know how i could solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First time you get the parent item in dutch :

```
Language languageDutch=Language.Parse("nl-nl");

   ////parentItemId is the item under you want to create child
   Item parentItem=Sitecore.Context.Item.GetItem(parentItemId, Language languageDutch)
```

after you create child item in dutch like :

`parentItem.AddItem("child item name",TemplateId)` .